# How to show timestamps in Chrome 103 console?

Tags: google-chrome

Google search's answer:

[image: Google search's answer]

Actual settings:

[image: Actual settings]

I think things have changed since Google's answer to that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The checkbox has been moved to Settings.

Press <kbd>F1</kbd> from inside dev tools.
Under the Console heading, you'll find `Show timestamps`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: An anti user-friendly move by the DevTools team.